# Using Microsoft integrated windows authentication with WCF but without IIS

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication

Is there a way to get the behavior of Microsoft Integrated Windows Authentication w/o having to deploy using IIS?   We have our own standalone C#/WCF WebServer and we would like to add this functionality.  We cannot use IIS as part of our deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the ClientCredentialType

```
WebHttpBinding whb = ... ;
whb.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
```

and later get the WindowsIdentity with

```
WindowsIdentity identity =  ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
```

Answer (score 0):

WCF is "**self hosting**". That's mean, you don't have to have an IIS in order to run it on the server (Depending on your implementations of of course). You can even run it on client's computers.

Look at this article for more information about WCF authentications:

[Authentication and Authorization in WCF Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

And an example in this article:

[Authenticate with a User Name and Password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131(v=vs.110).aspx)